# Modify Range in Class AllowEditRanges

Tags: excel, vba

I already set item manually with name “Test”  in Class AllowEditRange.
I Just need to change range of this item by VBA , But I could not.
I tried the following code , but it do nothing (no error raised)
Thanks for everyone can help.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Modify_User_EditRange()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges("Test").Range = ws.Range("A2:A8")

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges("Test").Range` returns a `Range` object and by default, refers to its `Value` property (So your code is actually saying "modify the range value to `ws.Range("A2:A8")` value") . To change the `Range` - You need to use `Set` e.g. `Set ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges("Test").Range = ws.Range("A2:A8")`

Comment: @Raymond Wu works perfectly , could you post as answer ,may be anyone can benefit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges("Test").Range` returns a `Range` object so to modify it, you need to use the `Set` statement:

`Set ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges("Test").Range = ws.Range("A2:A8")`